# How to build a program with 2 different values of a variable in CMake

Tags: c++, build, cmake, compiler-flags

I've recently ported my `Qt` project from `qmake` to `CMake`.
My main program contains a value which depends on a `#define` directive.

I want to specify that define directive externally via `CMake` and build 3 differently named versions of the same executable.

How should I do it?

I've seen `set_target_properties` but this only works for libraries and not for executables.

For example I want that the following program,

```
 int main()
 {

    cout << BUILDTYPE << endl;
 }
```

it's compiled in 3 different flavors (3 executables) based on the `BUILDTYPE "define"`
For example in my `CMakeLists.txt` I want to specify

```
add_executable(myAppV1 -DBUILDTYPE=1)
add_executable(myAppV2 -DBUILDTYPE=2)
add_executable(myAppV3 -DBUILDTYPE=3)
```

but this is not the correct syntax.
Some hint?
and I get 3 executables which prints

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you sure that `set_target_properties` does not work? How about this one:

```
set_target_properties(myAppV1 PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-DBUILDTYPE=1")
```

or:

```
set_target_properties(myAppV1 PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "BUILDTYPE=1")
```

On my machine it works:

```
add_executable(myAppV1 main.cpp)
add_executable(myAppV2 main.cpp)
set_target_properties(myAppV1 PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "BUILDTYPE=1")
set_target_properties(myAppV2 PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "BUILDTYPE=2")
```

Comment: Thank you!
I have to move the set_target_properties after the add_executable and use it in the second version you wrote

add_executable(myAppv1 main.cpp)
set_target_properties(myAppV1 PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "BUILDTYPE=1")

but NOT this way
add_executable(myAppv1 main.cpp)
set_target_properties(myAppV1 PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "-DBUILDTYPE=1")

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be:

```
mkdir two directory
buildflavor1
buildflavor2
```

In the first sub directory run:

```
cmake -DFLAVOR=OPTION1 ..
```

in the second run:

```
run cmake -DFLAVOR=OPTION2 ..
```

So two executable with same name with different compilation flag with is own feature `.o` and so on.